# replace negative numbers with zero in all columns of a tab separated file

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I want to replace with sed or awk or even in perl **all negative numbers** with **zeros**. Just the negative numbers, I say this because there are negative nan (-nan) and I want to keep it. But it would be nice know how to change also the "-nan" string to zero value in case of I would need in a future.

I find some answers related to replacement of negative values but just for one specific column, in my case I have at least 9 columns with positive and negative numbers (from 2nd column to 9th column)

I let you an example of my input file:

```
00001   0.0110712   -0.00113939 -3.67103e-05    0.013348    0.000541701 -nan    0.0086972   0.0130983   0.000482555 
00002   0.346079    0.0195448   0.00891779  0.327209    0.00170761  0.000914081 0.28396 0.32112 0.00071226  
00003   0.000468029 -nan    -nan    0.000470196 -nan    -nan    6.86508e-05 0.000428319 -nan
```

Thanks beforehand!, 
Best!

Comment: How come you don't know what language you are using? Where's your code? What problem are you having?

Comment: @ikegami I was trying with sed and awk using this codes: awk '{$0=($0<0)?0:$0}0' OFS='\t' test.txt |||| sed *'s/^-.*/0/' test.txt ... but no one works well

Comment: I... must... upvote... the... negative... -1... to... zero...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just comparing with zero seems to work in awk:

```
$ awk -vOFS='\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i<0)$i=0}1' file
00001   0.0110712   0   0   0.013348    0.000541701 -nan    0.0086972   0.0130983   0.000482555
00002   0.346079    0.0195448   0.00891779  0.327209    0.00170761  0.000914081 0.28396 0.32112 0.00071226  
00003   0.000468029 -nan    -nan    0.000470196 -nan    -nan    6.86508e-05 0.000428319 -nan
```

For the additional requirements raised in the comments, if you also want to change "-nan" values to zero, you can write:

```
awk -vOFS='\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i<0||$i=="-nan")$i=0}1' file
```

Or if you want to change the "-nan" values to "NaN" you can do:

```
awk -vOFS='\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i<0)$i=0;if($i=="-nan")$i="NaN"}}1' file
```

Comment: thanks, it works correctly! what I wonder now is: how change values of "-nan" into zeros also or into "NaN" in order to use this table in R. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Gaferolo: I added two more examples with the additional requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It's tagged perl, so:

```
perl -lane 'print join "\t", (map { $_ < 0 ? 0 : $_ } @F)'
```

Comment: would you explain what the lane and the @F do, I get the rest.

Comment: thanks it works, but I don't know which of both perl or awk last more, So If you have any Ideas of which program could be faster than other @Sobrique

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed 's/\([[:space:]]*\)-[0-9.e-]\{1,\}/\10/g' file
```

or using ERE:

```
sed -r 's/(\s*)-[0-9.e-]+/\10/g' file
```

Comment: it also change the "-nan" into "0nan"

Comment: thanks it works, but I wonder if which code could be apropriate to do this, awk, sed, perl.... I am looking for the faster way

Comment: I want to know how to change also '-nan' values to zeros. some suggestions? Thanks